# Multiplex RedirectMatch URL Path with Apache MOD_REWRITE

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I cannot find a way to perform this permanent redirection:
From:

```
http://it.example.com/oldpath
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/it/newpath
```

Where "it" is the language  id, it can be also "fr", "de", "en" and so on.
I supposed this could work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://(.*).example.com/oldpath/ http://www.example.com/$1/newpath/
```

But it is not working, because of the included path. But removing it I lose the parametric information about the language. How to perform such operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use mod_rewrite and not mod_alias to match against the hostname.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you @Panama-Jack! I can't try in my dev environment because for some reason wildcard are not working, I'll test it soon on stage (I don't get the %1). After this rule, at this point, I should have `http://www.example.com/it/newpath/...`, may I now add further rules such as: `RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)/newpath/(.*)/ http://www.example.com/$1/newpath/$2/more/` To redirect e.g., from `http://www.example.com/it/newpath/test1` to `http://www.example.com/it/newpath/test1/more/` ? Redirects are working, but I can't test if they'll work after the previous rule (Also RewriteLog is not working). TX!

Comment: Ok, the answer to the previous question is yes.